# Undocumented outputs with aspell spell checking?

Tags: aspell

I am writing a spell checker for a load of language files in a large projekt using java and aspell.
'Problem is that the application is built in Swedish with an optional English client, so I must use language checks for both languages. This works fine with aspell-en and aspell-sv, but one problem appears when checking language files in Swedish.

According to the aspell documentation page: http://aspell.net/0.50-doc/man-html/6_Writing.html
down at the "Format of the Data Stream" headline, the possible outputs from a word check is either '*', '&' or '#'. For some reason I seem to receive the output '-' from some words in the Swedish aspell checker.

Does anybody have any experience with using aspell in languages other than English, do you know what this output means? Worth mentioning also is that the '-' does not come with any explanation or "failure message", so I don't know what it is supposed to symbolize.